# Jquery Validation error message in the form

Tags: jquery-validate

I am trying to display a validation error message beside the form field  reportFileURL. Here is the code which submits the form

```
var uploadForm = $("#uploadMVRContentForm");
        uploadForm.validate({
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                uploadForm.ajaxSubmit({
                    dataType:'json',
                    success:function(result){
                        if(result.success === true ){
                            mvrContentFormDiv.hide();
                            document.getElementById('uploadMVRContentForm').reset();
                            displayMVRContent();
                        }
                        else{
                            alert(result.errorMessage);
                            return false;

                        }

                    }
                });
            },rules: {
                "mediaValueReport.mainTitle": "required",
                "mediaValueReport.reportFileURL": "required",
                "mediaValueReport.indexPageImageURL":"required",
                "mediaValueReport.landingPageImageURL":"required",
                "mediaValueReport.seoURL":"required",
                "reportDate":"required"
            },
            errorElement: "span"
        });
```

I am using a alertbox to display that the report file is url. Please suggest me a solution for this.

With errorPlacement

```
 else{
        var error = result.errorMessage;
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.insertAfter("#reportFileURL")
        }

        return false;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the error placement function, like so

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {}
```

here's a [link to the plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate) under the options tab explaining how to use it in detail

Comment: Thanks for the info,  I Added in the else block but its not working... above is the updated code..

Comment: the errorPlacement function is for the jQuery plugin, which happens on the client side prior to the ajax post and the else should work as long as result.success == false and result.errorMessage is not empty. if those conditions are met, do you ate least see an alert box?

Comment: yes...  the alert box is visible if the results.success=false

Comment: is it displaying the message?

Comment: cool so it's working then.  if you need to then display these errors, which could be backend processing errors, you should then pass this to another function to display a modal div popup or a fade in box to show additional errors outside of the form validation; just a suggestion  let me know if you further assistance, always glad to help.